# How to insert records from table to another without duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have two tables t1 and t2. t1 has duplicated values. I need to insert all records from t1 to t2, but I don't want duplicates to occur in t2. I tried the following command which seems to me correct and no syntax error when I run it but the problem, it has 0 effect. No records from t1 inserted in t2.

```
insert into test.t2 (name2) 
select name1 from test.t1 where NOT EXISTS (select name2 from test.t2);
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
insert into test.t2(name2) 
select distinct name1 from test.t1 where name1 NOT IN(select name2 from test.t2);
```

OR

```
insert into test.t2(name2) 
select distinct name1 from test.t1 t1 where NOT EXISTS(select name2 from test.t2 t2 where t1.name1=t2.name2);
```

Comment: Not sure about mySql, but in Oracle at least, you can't say "where name1 NOT EXISTS" - it's just "where NOT EXISTS"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index (of one or more columns) and then use the MySQL replace command.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_name2 ON t2 (name2);

REPLACE INTO t2 (name2) values ($name1);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've go two options here, one involves not duplicating the data on your insert, the second being to ignore duplicates when inserting.

To de-duplicate from the `SELECT` call you'd use `DISTINCT:

```
INSERT INTO test.t2 (name2) SELECT name1 FROM test.t1 WHERE name1 NOT IN (SELECT name2 FROM test.t2)
```

You can also add a `UNIQUE` index to avoid this problem in the first place:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name2 (name2)
```

Note that you will get an error if there is already duplicate data in `t2`, so you may have to clean it up beforehand.

Then you can add data with the `IGNORE` option:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test.t2 (name2) SELECT name1 FROM TEST.t1
```

The unique index approach will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: the unique will raise an error and will not perform the insert. I already have a lot of duplicated records in t1 and I need to insert them in t2.

Answer (score 0):

I need to insert data from user to another user and when write this statement
.....

```
insert into trep12.jobhead
select
*
from
wsfin04.jobhead
where
wsfin04.jobhead.job_no not in (select job_no from trep12.jobhead)
and wsfin04.jobhead.CHASS_NO not in (select CHASS_NO from trep12.jobhead)
and rdate between '01-jul-15'
and '01-oct-15'
and job_type = 1;
```

.....
the result is 0 rows created.

Answer (score -1):

this should do it: 
`INSERT IGNORE INTO test.t2 SELECT name2 FROM test.t1`
Selects from one table and inserts into another.

Comment: -1: a) OP gave you the columns to use - no need to make up an example using made up cols.  b) this would insert dups - which OP doesn't want.

Comment: c) will fail if test.t2 has other columns (OP never indicated it didn't); d) should be `SELECT name1 from test.t1` (not `name2`)

Comment: I give up... I've studied the other answer. Cool stuff.