# mysql data copy from one table to another without duplicate value

Tags: mysql

we have 2 table . we want to transfer table_1 data to table_2 with out duplicate data.

```
Table_1
----------
1

2

3

4
----------

Table_2
----------
2

4
----------
```

now we want to transfer Table_1 Values to Table_2 without duplicate.
please tell me how to do in mysql query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert records from table to another without duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569642/how-to-insert-records-from-table-to-another-without-duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into table_2 
select * 
  from table_1 
 where column not in (select column from table_2);
```

Answer (score 2):

First create unique index on the column (you want to keep unique) in table_2.

Now use below statement-

```
insert ignore into table_2 select * from table_1;
```